# Aggregation of three collections, Get jobs from job_posting collection of users those have notification_status is true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I have three collections 1.user_details{field: user_favorite_company_notification_status:boolean, user_id} [user details collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd5iQ.png)
 2.fav_companies{company_id, jobseeker_id} [favorite companies collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBcvG.png)
3.job_postings { company_id, enable_status, job_created_at} [job postings collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBU5U.png).
I need to get details of job_postings of favourite companies of users who have notification status is true.

I have tried to join all these collections to get job posts of those companies who are favourite companies for users. So I need to get details of all users who have notification status true and then find the favourite companies of those users and then get job posting for favourite companies.

```
  db.collection('user_details').aggregate([
        {$match : {user_favorite_company_notification_status: true}},
        {$lookup: {from : 'favorite_companies' ,localField : '_id', foreignField: 'jobseeker_id', as: 'fav_companies'}},
        { "$unwind": "$fav_companies" },
        {$lookup: {from : 'job_postings' , "pipeline":[
            {"$match":{
                $and:[
                    {company_id: "fav_companies.company_id"},
                    {enable_status: true},
                    {job_created_at: { $gt: previous_day}}
                    ]
                }
            }
            ], as: 'jobposts'}},
      ]).toArray((err, result)=>{
          console.log(result);
      })
```

Comment: Could you post the sample documents from all the collections

Comment: Ditto. The collection and field names in your query don't really match your description of the database. 
For example, it looks like `user_favorite_company_notification_status` should simply be `notification_status`.

Comment: @DavidSiegal there are same fields in my database and in my code  which is `user_favorite_company_notification_status` and I have written `notification_status` only for reference purpose.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yeah I have uploded screenshots of collections.

Comment: As i have checked in your job_postings there is field job_enable_status but instead you have written enable_status in your code , First change it and check.

Comment: @Priyank I have changed but It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     db.collection('user_details').aggregate([
    {$match : {user_favorite_company_notification_status: true}},
    {$lookup: {from : 'favorite_companies' ,"let": { "user_id": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
        { "$match": {
            "$expr" : {
                "$and":[
                    {$eq:["$jobseeker_id","$$user_id"]},
                    {$eq:["$liked",true]}
                ]
            }
        } }
      ], as: 'fav_companies'}},
    { "$unwind": "$fav_companies"
     }
,
{$lookup: {from : 'job_postings' ,"let": { "companyId": "$fav_companies.company_id" },
"pipeline": [
    { "$match": {
        "$expr" : {
            "$and":[
                {$eq:["$company_id","$$companyId"]},
                {$eq:["$enable_status",true]},
                {$gt:["$job_created_at" , previous_day ] }

            ]
        }
    } }
  ], as: 'jobposts'}},
  { "$unwind": "$jobposts"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Update your code with below one and check.

```
db.collection('user_details').aggregate([
    {$match : {user_favorite_company_notification_status: true}}, ,
    {$lookup: {from : 'favorite_companies' ,localField : '_id', foreignField: 'jobseeker_id', as: 'fav_companies'}},
    { "$unwind": "$fav_companies" },
    { 
        $lookup: {
            from: "job_postings",
            let: { company_id : "$fav_companies.company_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { 
                    $match:
                    { 
                        $expr:
                        { 
                            $and: [ 
                                    $eq : [{"$job_enable_status" : true}],
                                    $gt : [{"$job_created_at" : previous_day } ]
                                 ]

                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "fav_companies.jobposts"
        } 
    }
]).exec((err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Let me know once checked

Comment: it throws error `errmsg:"Each element of the 'pipeline' array must be an object"`